# A word for "a person who does whatever he wants"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm looking for a word (or phrase) for describing a person who acts according to his own will, who does what his heart says, and who does whatever he wants. I tried to search in many (more than 20) dictionaries but found nothing relevant.
So, please provide a word or more for describing such a person.
Do the following sentences mean what I want?

- He follows his heart.
- He follows his mind.
- He's a happy-go-lucky person.

Comment: "free spirit" is the first word came to my mind.

Comment: I would love to add an answer, but apparently I still need two more +1's to my other answers before I can add it to this question (because it has "high activity").

Answer (score 9):

There are many words, which emphasize different meaning. Some are negative.

Pleasure aspect of doing whatever you want: *bon vivant*, *hedonist*, *pleasure seeker*.

Going wherever you want, possibly new places (metaphorically too): *globetrotter*, *explorer*, *pioneer*.

Free thought, defiance: *maverick*, *liberal*, *free thinker*, *nonconformist*.

Disregard for traditional social structures: *bohemian*, *hippie*, *beatnik*.

Disregard for manner and social grace: *boor*, *barbarian*, *brute*, *philistine*.

Ambition: *doer*, *achiever*.

Disregard for law: *criminal*, *outlaw*, *gangster*, *robber*, *lawbreaker*, *desperado*, etc.

Acting in self-interest without regard for trust: *back-stabber*, *snitch*, *cheater*, *two-timer*.

Acting in self-interest without regard for others: *egoist*, *narcissist*.

Comment: What a detailed and insightful answer! My additions would be: loose cannon, renegade, cowboy. These are used to describe maverick cops in movies.

Comment: I think "free spirit" as brought up in the comments fits in the *bohemian, hippie, beatnik* category.

Answer (score 0):

I think the adjective for this is "capricious"

> given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behavior.
> "it's terrible to feel our livelihood hinges on a capricious boss" (Lexico)

Answer (score 0):

Great answers already, but missing is "self-determined":

**[Self-determination](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-determination)**

> 1. determination by oneself or itself, without outside influence.
> 2. freedom to live as one chooses, or to act or decide without consulting another or others.
> 3. the determining by the people of the form their government shall have, without reference to the wishes of any other nation, especially by people of a territory or former colony.

Which relates strongly to:

**[autonomous](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/autonomous)**

> 1. Government.
>
>    a. self-governing; independent; subject to its own laws only.
>
>    b. pertaining to an autonomy, or a self-governing community.
> 2. having autonomy; not subject to control from outside; independent
> 3. (of a machine, device, etc.) able to operate with little or no human control or intervention:

And as mentioned in the comments:

**[free spirit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/free_spirit)**

> One who is a nonconformist or who does not recognize the authority of others.